# "a ten years old boy" or "a ten year old boy"

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers, adjective-phrases

> 1) a ten years old boy is sitting on the couch.
>
> 2) a ten year old boy is sitting on the couch.
>
> 3) a ten-years old boy is sitting on the couch.
>
> 4) a ten-year old boy is sitting on the couch.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Generally, when units of measure are used as adjectives, or as part of a compound noun, they are singular. When expressed as simple nouns, they are plural. Thus,

> A ten-year-old boy is sitting on the couch.
>
> The boy sitting on the couch is ten years old.
>
> The boy sitting on the couch is a ten-year-old.

As for the hyphenation, exact usage is a matter of style, but the hyphen will determine how to interpret the phrase.

> Ten year-old trees

refers to ten trees which are each one year old, whereas

> Ten-year-old trees

refers to some trees which are each ten years old.

Comment: Whether to hyphenate at all or not is definitely a matter of style, but I don't imagine there would be many people who'd endorse *Ten-year old trees*. It looks truly awful to me.

Comment: Yeah, "Ten-year old trees" doesn't make any sense. It implies that both "ten-year" and "old" separately modify "trees". If you'd edit that example out, I'd upvote this answer as it is otherwise quite good.

Answer (score 10):

**X year old** is a phrase that can be either an adjective, noun or a construct of the verb to be

When used as an adjective the correct thing to say is **year old**.

> A **ten-year-old** boy is sitting on the couch.

When used as a verb construct it must agree with the noun in terms of quantity.

> The boy is sitting on the couch is **10 years old**.

You want to use it as an adjective in your sentences so the number 4 is correct.

Comment: *Complement*, I think, not *construct*. :)

Comment: @StoneyB: It's certainly a [complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(linguistics)) in Persian Cat's second example - but unless I'm much mistaken, it would still be a "complement" in, say, *"The boy sitting on the couch is **a 10 year old**."* Sure, it's a "noun" as well there, but that just goes to show "adjective/complement" isn't really a useful way of defining the different contexts where singular/plural are idiomatically used.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Too true. It's a wonder *anybody* speaks the language fluently.

Answer (score 1):

1. When used before a noun as an adjective, use '' -year-old":

> A ten-year-old boy is sitting on the couch.

2. When you simply state the age of someone, write "years old" and do not hyphenate:

> The boy sitting on the couch is 10 years old.

Note, in this case, you can omit the part "years old" :

> He is 10. = He is 10 years old.