# Shouldn't "five minute walk" be "five minutes walk" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, singular-vs-plural, attributive-nouns

Recently, while skimming through an article I came across a sentence which is as follows.

> The five minute walk will connect you with life.

My rationale says it should have been "five **minutes**" and not "five **minute**". Kindly advise where am I going wrong?

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6434/a-ten-years-old-boy-or-a-ten-year-old-boy. Welcome to ELL!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

J.R. and Ingmar are both correct, but I'd like add to what they've said by defining some of the terms involved. Overall, it's quite common for nouns to modify other nouns.

> The **five minute walk** will connect you with life.

Because *five* and *minute* don't agree in number, you can tell that these words are being used differently than they ordinarily would be. The reason they aren't in agreement is that they represent one, compound word. The words are to be taken collectively, in other words. They do still follow the rule that modifiers need to agree in number, and while not obvious, they do agree in number. That is to say that *five-minute* agrees with *a walk*.

The plural, in your example, would be *the five-minute walks*.

> The five-minute walks that I take daily are therapeutic.

And as others have pointed out, *five-minute* is being used as one whole unit to modify *walk*. Although some writers choose to hyphenate noun adjuncts such as this to indicate they are [*a compound modifier*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier), a hyphen is **not required.** I usually recommend using hyphens, but ultimately, it's a style choice. ***If*** the meaning of the sentence can change significantly when the words are **not** viewed in sum as a single modifier, then they should be hyphenated for clarity.

While adjectives are the most common part of speech used to modify nouns, they are **not the only** part of speech that can do so. In this case, the subject of your sentence is the entire noun-clause *five-minute walk*, and *five minute* is quantifying the walk by indicating the length of the walk in terms of time.

These words are most commonly referred to as [*attributive nouns*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/help/dictnotes/attrib.htm) or [*noun adjuncts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)

> My rationale says it should have been "five minutes" & not "five
>   minute". Kindly advise where am I going wrong? Thank you.

When you say *five minutes*, you're using *five* differently. And while you're still using this pair as a combined modifier, you're actually changing **how** they are modifying the nouns *walk* and *walking*. You know that they are to be considered separately because they **do** agree in number.

Compare the following:

> This **five minute walk** will connect you with life.

-versus-

> These **five minutes of walking** will connect you with life.

In the first sentence, *this five-minute walk* is emphasizing that this is a  walk that *takes five minutes to complete.* Similarly, other nouns can used to quantify walk in other ways. While *five minute walk* quantifies *walk* **temporally**, people often say that they go for *5k* or *3 mile* walks/runs to quantify the distance. Either way, you're emphasizing length/duration.

In the second sentence *these five minutes* still modifies *walking*, but in this case *five* **also** modifies *minutes* itself, which is why they must agree in number. But they're still working as a compound modifier in that they indicate the length of the walk.

You'll note that it follows the same rule in that the pair of nouns don't agree in number. You either go for a *5k/3.1 **mile walk***, or *you walk **3.1 miles***, with *walk* being a verb in the latter.

[*The Chicago Manual of Style Online*, 16th Ed.](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch05/ch05_sec022.html?para=) has a good explanation of attributive nouns. They don't suggest whether or not the adjuncts should be hyphenated, so if you're following *The Chicago Manual's* style, then hyphenating the words is completely optional. I'll link the site, but since it's subscription-based (another pair of attributive nouns), I'll copy and paste the text directly below:

> ***5.22 Nouns as adjectives***
>
> Words that are ordinarily nouns sometimes function as other parts of
>   speech, such as adjectives or verbs. A noun-to-adjective shift takes
>   place when a noun modifies another noun **{the morning newspaper} {a
>   state legislature} {a varsity sport} (morning, state, and varsity
>   function as adjectives).** These are also termed attributive nouns.
>   **Occasionally the use of a noun as an adjective can produce an
>   ambiguity.** For example, the phrase fast results can be read as meaning
>   either “rapid results” or (less probably but possibly) “the outcome of
>   a fast.” Sometimes the noun and its adjectival form can be used
>   interchangeably—for example, prostate cancer and prostatic cancer both
>   refer to cancer of the prostate gland. **But sometimes the use of the
>   noun instead of the adjective may alter the meaning—for instance, a
>   study group is not necessarily a studious group.** A preposition may be
>   needed to indicate a noun’s relationship to other sentence elements.
>   But if the noun functions as an adjective, the preposition must be
>   omitted; at times this can result in a vague phrase—for example, voter
>   awareness (awareness of voters or by them?). Context might suggest
>   what preposition is implied, but a reader may have to deduce the
>   writer’s meaning.

Comment: This is a good answer, with a lot of interesting information. However I find I must contradict you in one place. I don't find this to be accurate: "They don't suggest whether or not the adjuncts should be hyphenated, so if you're following The Chicago Manual's style, then hyphenating the words is completely optional." The CMS provides a great deal more information about hyphenation in their [Hyphenation Table](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/images/ch07_tab01.pdf) than you quote here. The table specifically states that "number+noun" is to be "Hyphenated before a noun, otherwise open."

Comment: Can you use _lenth_ instead of _long_, as in _a three-quarter **length** coat_?

Answer (score 13):

When a modifier comes directly before a noun, we say that it's in  **attributive** position:

- Attributive noun: a **chicken** pie
- Attributive adjective: a **tasty** pie

When a noun is used attributively, you typically put it in the singular:

> a **chicken** pie
>   *a **chickens** pie 　*(non-standard)*

This tendency is so strong that a few words appear in the singular even though they normally have no singular form:

> a **trouser** press
>   a **scissor** kick

Outside of attributive constructions, the singular *scissor* and *trouser* do not exist in standard English.

Although it's not an absolute rule, when you use a multi-word noun phrase attributively, you typically use a hyphen:

> a **five-minute** walk 　*(recommended, but not required)*
>   a **five minute** walk

In fact, none of these are absolute rules.  Particularly in British English, you may see one of two plural forms used:

> a **five minutes** walk　 *(plural)*
>   a **five minutes'** walk　 *(plural genitive)*

In *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*, Quirk et. al say that "the plural attributive construction is on the increase".  They identify a few common uses of attributive plurals, and I'll include some of them here, but I don't intend for this answer to be exhaustive (and I don't think their full categorization is, either):

1. Words which have no singular form (called *pluralia tantum*) appear in the plural, with a couple exceptions as noted above:

   > a **customs** officer
2. Plurals are sometimes used to express variety:

   > a **soft drinks** manufacturer

   Here, Quirk et al. say *drinks* means "kinds of drink".  But they note that this is not universal, giving the counterexample "car manufacturer".
3. Plurals are sometimes used to rule out a singular interpretation, particularly in the names of institutions:

   > The **Parks** Department
   >   the **heavy chemicals** industry

   Here, *parks* means "multiple parks", and *heavy chemicals* means "heavy chemicals in general".

There are other uses as well.  So as you can see, plurals aren't necessarily wrong in attributive position.  However, as a rule, I recommend you stick to the singular unless you know a particular phrase is usually pluralized.

Answer (score 7):

The singular is fine but a hyphen should be used:

> The five-minute walk will connect you with life.

You would use the plural, though, if you weren't using "five-minute" as a modifier:

> The walk will connect you with life, and last five minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Minute here is a noun being used as an adjective, and unlike in many other languages adjectives in English are inflexible, i.e. they do not have to "agree" in number or gender with the noun they modify. Unsurprisingly, therefore, they do not possess a plural form (in general). So for example it's: Two small (not smalls) fines and two ten-pound (not pounds) fines.

Answer (score 1):

It is *not* normal in British English to say

> a five minutes walk　
>   a five minutes' walk

By contrast, you may well see

> five minutes walk　
>   five minutes' walk

As in:

> The shop is five minutes walk away.
>   I live just five minutes' walk from here.

Answer (score -1):

**five minute** is used as **adjective:**

> a five minute dance

**five minutes** is used as **adjective plus plural noun**:

> dance for five minutes

although *five* in this context can also be regarded as a **determiner**.

Answer (score -1):

> The five minute walk will connect you with life.

Here, the emphasis is not on the "five minute" but on the "walk" and thus the "five minute" acts as an adjective and should be accompanied by the noun and should be typed as "five-minute walk."