# Is "release date" grammatically correct?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-phrases, attributive-nouns

Why I always heard something like *"Iphone release date and price unveiled"*. Shouldn't it be **"be released"** by someone? (Iphone can't release anything itself as a lifeless object)

I look up some the online dictionaries, none of it says "release" can be used as "adjective" (in order to describe "date"), and even if it can, it should be "the release date of Iphone and price unveiled".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Yes, it is.

Here's why:

- Nouns can *sometimes* be used *like* adjectives.

  > <sub>[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)</sub>
  >
  > Noun adjuncts are nouns that modify other nouns.

  (e.g. language learners, man eater, work clothes, chicken soup, etc.)
- How does this work for three nouns? (Iphone + release + date)

  They work for as many nouns as you like.<sup>†</sup>

  (e.g. baseball game ticket price increase proposal, waste water treatment process)

  These are called *[noun chains](http://www.grammar.com/noun-chain/)*. Here, only the last word functions as a noun.
- Therefore, "Iphone release date" can be parsed as:

  > (Iphone->(release->date))

  And yes; this can be rephrased to:

  > the date of release of the Iphone

Comment: I agree with you! +1

Comment: While maybe irrelevant to this site, I somehow feel it's interesting to mention that in Dutch these noun chains have to be concatenated into one word. So "baseball game ticket price increase proposal" in Dutch is "honkbalspelkaartjesprijsverhogingsvoorstel". You can make words as long as you want :).

Answer (score 26):

## They're attributive nouns.

Here, *release* is an **attributive noun**.  It modifies the head noun directly following it:

> **release** date

Together they form the nominal *release date*, meaning "the date of [something]'s release".  Add an article to that, and we get a complete **noun phrase**:

> [ The **release** date ]<sub>noun phrase</sub> had yet to be determined.

Your example, though, is written in [**headlinese**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese), a style in which articles and other words are often omitted.  In this case, *have been* is also omitted (before *unveiled*).

It also uses a slightly more complex structure than the above: it coordinates *release date* with *price* to form a larger nominal, *release date and price*.  This nominal is modified by another attributive noun, *iPhone*:

> <strike>the</strike> **iPhone** [ [ **release** date ] and price ] <strike>have been</strike> unveiled

This could be considered a reduced version of two full noun phrases:

> [ <strike>the</strike> **iPhone** [ **release** date ] ] and [ <strike>the **iPhone**</strike> price ] <strike>have been</strike> unveiled

I've bolded the attributive modifiers: *iPhone*, *release*, and *iPhone* again.  The omitted words here are stricken through.  The noun phrases mean in turn "the date of the iPhone's release" and "the price of the iPhone".

---

## They're not adjectives.

Nouns can be used as [**attributive modifiers**](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/grammar/attrib_sli.pdf), just like adjectives.  It's a basic function that nouns have, and every single noun can be used this way.  In fact, other nouns modify other nouns all the time:

> **chicken** soup
>   an **atom** bomb
>   a **release** date
>   a **sports** magazine

Some people say that *sports* and *chicken* here are "adjectives" or "nouns acting as adjectives".  [**These people are wrong.**](http://ling.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/ZAA_final_proof.pdf)  How do we know?

1. They don't inflect like adjectives:

   > **hot** soup
   >   **hotter** soup
   >   **hottest** soup
   >
   > **chicken** soup
   >   ***chickener** soup
   >   ***chickenest** soup
2. They don't accept adverbs as modifiers:

   > **hot** soup
   >   **very hot** soup
   >   **chicken** soup
   >   ***very chicken** soup
3. They often don't function as predicative complements:

   > It was a **dangerous** bomb.
   >   It was an **atom** bomb.
   >   The bomb seemed **dangerous**.
   >   *The bomb seemed **atom**.
   >   He made the bomb **dangerous**.
   >   *He made the bomb **atom**.
4. They don't function postpositively:

   > This is **hot** soup.
   >   This is **chicken** soup.
   >   This soup is something **hot**.
   >   *This soup is something **chicken**.
5. [Attributive nouns are sometimes marked for number](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14290/five-minute-or-minutes/14312#14312):

   > a **sports** magazine
   >   a **customs** officer
   >   a **soft drinks** manufacturer
   >   the **heavy chemicals** industry
   >   The **Parks** Department

   Most attributive nouns are unmarked for number:

   > **chicken** soup
   >   ***chickens** soup
   >   a **trouser** press
   >   a **trousers** press  *(nonstandard?)*

   But adjectives are **never** so marked:

   > *a **hots** soup
   >   *several **beautifuls** walls

In short, nouns remain noun-like when used attributively.  Nouns don't suddenly become adjectives or adjective-like when you make use of one of their basic functions.  Their main similarity to adjectives in this position is in being unmarked for number, but even there we can see a difference, and one that's widening over time—the plural attributive construction is becoming more and more common.

Sometimes attributive nouns are reanalyzed as adjectives.  For example, in recent decades people have started to say *funner*, *funnest*, and *really fun*.  For these speakers, *fun* really is a full-fledged adjective, and we can tell because it displays the characteristics associated with one!

But for the most part, there are clear differences between attributive nouns and adjectives, so there's very little motivation to use the word "adjective" in describing this sort of usage.

Comment: ++ But *scissors kick* is an awkward example: a) *Scissors kick* is in fact in widespread use, and b) in many dialects/idiolects *scissors* is singular - *Could you bring me a scissors, please.*

Comment: @StoneyB Oh, I starred it because I thought *scissors kick* was nonstandard.  (I grabbed that example from Quirk et al., but I see looking at corpora that you're correct.)  I'll go with *trousers press* for my example, then, since I think that *trouser press* is the normal usage, but I'll mark it "(nonstandard?)" since I'm not sure.

Comment: @snailplane, your explanation terms are better.+1.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot *star* the answer - this is brilliantly executed snailplane :)

Comment: You only reckon that "chicken" can't be an adjective because you're jealous that my soup is chickener than your soup. Your soup is barely chicken at all. My soup is the chickenest soup around.

Comment: That's a nonstandard zero derivation.  You can do it, but it's nonstandard and informal, which is certainly not the case every time we say "chicken soup".

Comment: I ordered some suzette, I said/Could you please make that crepe?  -Bob Dylan

Comment: @tobyink I think you'd have to go with "chickeny" instead of "chicken" for that to sound right, and even then I think it's a stretch. "My soup is chikenier, yours is barely chickeny, mine is the chickeniest." Still...sounds odd. But better than just trying to use *chicken* as an adjective.

Comment: "a scissors"?  That sounds just as weird and unlikely as "a pants".

Answer (score 3):

I guess *iPhone release date* serves as a compound noun. In that case, it does not take anything. You may read it like this...

> *[iphone release date] and [price] unveiled*

*[Just to address your confusion about the device being released by itself -- Even if I believe it for a while that 'iphone' is the one releasing itself, it takes 'releases', doesn't it! - iPhone **releases** its date and price!]*