# The ownership s

Tags: possessives, attributive-nouns

My problem is about the possessive s (the *ownership s*) not that ending-s.

For example, we say, *America's Flag*, here the *America* has gotten one *ownership s* that is *America* is the owner of that *Flag*. And also we say, *Computer Science*, here that *Computer* doesn't get the *ownership s* (why?) even though we talk about *Science* which is of *Computer* (here).

My question is when we should add that *s* to the end of the first name which appear to be the owner of the second name?
Or how we can recognize what names get that *s*, please?

Comment: *Computer* in *Computer Science* is attributive. [This answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/22041/1513) could be helpful.

Comment: [Crossposted](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178548/the-possessive-s/178549#comment372413_178549) to ELU.

Comment: @Fantasier: Very complex for an English language newcomer. But thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

That is because *computer* is used attributive to *science*. A bit like an adjective, in the sense that *computer* describes *the kind of science*. It' snot an adjective though, because of the reasons in the post that Fantasier linked to.

You could say that the [noun *computer* "acts as" an *adjective*](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-adjective.htm).

It is the same thing that happens in other compound nouns, like

> history teacher
>   ticket office
>   race horse

Actually, the science does not belong to the computer (my computer is unable to show me any science that it possesses!) but rather, the *science* is *about computers*.

Comment: I came here as you had wanted it. OK I _somewhat_ got that how can I recognize where to use of that _s_ and where not to. But you said there is a clean rule in this case. If there really is some rule which according to that we can clearly identify where to and not to add that _s_ please tell me that rule. This solves the whole of the issue likely. Thanks.

Comment: No complete obvious final rule!?