# Are "Bashkir" and "Bashkirian" interchangeable adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, proper-nouns, demonyms

The language spoken by the dwellers of Bashkortostan is **[Bashkir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bashkir_language)** language. There's company named [**Bashkirian** Airlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BAL_Bashkirian_Airlines) but also another company named "[**Bashkir** Soda Company](http://investing.businessweek.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=26521442)". Are the two adjectives interchangeable? That is, could both **Bashkir** and **Bashkirian** be used as adjectives meaning *of or relating to [Bashkiria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bashkortostan)*, or would **Bashkir** be normally used only in relation to language or a person?

Or is there a distinction between business usage and usage in everyday speech? Are companies' choices of the nationality/language-related adjectives less confined?

Comment: In business names it does not matter. Usage in regular statements may be another matter.

Answer (score 2):

This example looks quite like, for example, Uzbekistan where the Uzbeks speak Uzbek and their national airline is Uzbekistan Airways.

Uzbek is a noun, but it can also be used as an adjective:

> Uzbek president asks Putin to help fight radical Islam

This will be the same for Bashkir, ie. the *Bashkir* president.

What's confusing things, though, is that Bashkortostan is also known as Bashkiria. This means you can also say, for example, the *Bashkirian* president. Either is acceptable.

I suspect that most native English speakers would go with Bashkirian, as it's the more generalised example. That is, Italy - Italian, Canada - Canadian, etc.

It's worth noting that national airlines are generally named for the country, so if it wasn't Bashkirian Airlines it would be Bashkortostan Airlines.

**Note**: Pakistan is the only '-stan' that I'm aware of where the rules are different. The country's Pakistan and the people are Pakistani. You would be at risk of causing offence if you tried to follow the rules for the other '-stans'.

Answer (score 0):

[*Bashkir*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bashkirs) is not used as an adjective in "Bashkir language" but as a noun functioning as an [attributive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/22041/5251).

So the relationship between *Bashkir* and *Bashkirian* might be similar to how *Italy* is a noun and *Italian* is an adjective.

Comment: Thanks, Helix! However, the Oxford Dictionaries list [Bashkir](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Bashkir) both as a noun and as an adjective. But even if it is a noun adjunct, I'm curious whether it's on par with *Bashkirian* in its adjective role.

Comment: What do you mean by on par? Usage-wise?

Comment: @CopperKettle Yes, but [dictionaries are wrong.](http://ling.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/ZAA_final_proof.pdf)

Comment: Yes, usage-wise. If a native speaker will feel okay reading "A Bashkir company has signed a contract with..", I will be satisfied. (0: Thanks, @snailboat!