# "Product list" vs "Products list"

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

I have a page with list of products. What is the correct name for this page?

> Product list

or

> Products list

And What's difference?

Comment: See also: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/24244/3281, http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14312/3281.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Product list

A *list* by definition is already plural, so using *product* (what kind of list) as a modifier is correct.

*Products List* might not necessarily be wrong, but a better way to use *products* would be:

> List of products.

Answer (score 7):

> Product list

It is the right variant. When you put the name of the list before the word "list", we use a singular.

> Example: product list, price list, number list.

Or you can call list using "list of" + name of the list.

> Example: list of products, list of prices, list of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, the practical reason it should be "product list" vs. "products list" is because "product list" should be a list where each list item is a single "product", because "products list" should be reserved for a list where each list item is itself a "list" of products (e.g., the root level list may be a list of the "product list" of each business or department).  The latter could of course also be expressed as the more technically precise, albeit wordy, "product list list".

Now that I mention it, re. "of" form, for "product list", the "of" form should be "list of *products*" or "list of *the product* of each product manager". And for "products list", the "of" form would be "list of product lists".