# Deal list or deals list

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I need to write a title of a section that is a list of deals. The title could be "List of deals" but I prefer a more concise form.
Since there are usually a lot of deals in the list is it correct to use a title like "Deals list" or should I write "Deal list"?

Comment: A good way to decide this kind of question is to plug some other words in and see how they sound: *address list* or *addresses list*, *car list* or *cars list*?

Comment: Deal list. In his case it is used as an adjective so you don't use the plural form.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner thank you, it should be an answer. Anyway I don't understand how can it be an adjective since I can change it to "List of deals". An adjective like "red" can never be re-phrased as "List of red"

Comment: See also http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/57751/product-list-vs-products-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Noun as Adjective](http://www.englishleap.com/grammar/noun-as-adjective)***:

> - Sometimes in the English language, a noun is used to describe another noun; in other words, the first noun performs the function of an adjective. Look at the following examples:
>
>   - Basketball coach– here the noun basketball is being used to describe the noun coach
>   - Garment shop– here the noun garment is being used to describe the noun shop
>   - Painting exhibition– here the noun painting is being used to describe the noun exhibition.
>
>   In all the above examples, the first noun acts as an adjective.
> - ***In general, like adjectives, nouns being used as adjectives are used in the singular form, although in the case of certain words, like clothes, customs, sports, etc, an exception is made***. For example:
>
>   - Bathroom or bathrooms, and not bathsroom or bathsrooms
>   - Badminton racket or badminton rackets, and not badmintons racket or badmintons rackets.

(www.englishleap.com)

- In your case, you would use the singular form, that is "deal list".

Comment: thank you for the reported explanation, I've always had trouble understanding this singular-plural thing because my native language always use a form similar to "list of deals", hence no nouns used as adjective in that way.

Comment: +1 but you should cite your sources, posting a link is not enough.

Comment: Great explaination. Is parts list an exception of this rule? Because I did hardly find part list anywhere, but parts list almost everywhere. I have on the same sheet an pipe list table and found it strange to have one list with s and another one without.