# Zero rupees or zero rupee on the note?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

[5th Pillar](http://www.5thpillar.org/) is an NGO fighting against the corruption in India. As a part of non-cooperation movement against corruption, it has come up with a zero rupee note. Here is its image:

[image: Zero rupee note]

Now, my question is: Should we write 'zero rupees' or 'zero rupee'? 
'Zero rupee' is written everywhere in the [site](http://5thpillar.org/programs/zero-rupee-note).

Comment: Considering that the US ten-dollar bill is ten dollars (it's written TEN DOLLARS on the bill), I guess you could refer to the bill as the zero-rupee bill, and its value as zero rupees.

Comment: Related question on EL&U, [Why is “zero” plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38293/why-is-zero-plural).

Comment: @DamkerngT. Note that in India, 'bill' is ***never ever*** used for the currency note. For us, 'bill' **always** means what you get after purchasing some goods! You may remove the word 'bill' from the comment now to make it relevant.

Comment: @Rathony your comment is *actually* an answer to this! +1

Answer (score 8):

Usually, **attributive nouns in English are singular**; for longer treatment, see *[How do you use plural or singular form of an adjective?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24200)*.

You may consider units to be a variety of attributive noun, though there are additional guidelines, for example, for measurements. Different style guides define the guideline in different ways; the [*Oxford Style Guide* says](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/secondary/harts_rules/11-2-numbers-with-units-of-measure)

> Note that units of measurement retain their singular form when part of hyphenated compounds before other nouns
>
> > a five-pound note
> >     a two-mile walk
> >     a six-foot wall
> >     a 100-metre race

Integer and decimal amounts, on the other hand, are *always plural if not exactly one*. (Varun KN stated this in another way.) Thus,

- 1 inch
- 0.57 meters
- -3π radians
- 62 degrees
- 0 rupees

Thus, you have either

- a zero-rupee note
- a note worth zero rupees

Also see at EL&U

- [Is -1 singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9735/)
- [Plurality of numbers between -1 and 1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21792)
- [Why is “zero” plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38293)

Comment: -1 The question is about *'what to write there'* and **not** what do we **call** it. It is certainly a *zero-rupee* note, but what to **write** right there on the note is the question. And, the OP has already stated it:  *...it has come up with a zero rupee note...* He's clear about it!

Comment: @MaulikV It's not that clear in the question what he meant by "Should we write 'zero rupees' or 'zero rupee'?" The OP wrote "'Zero rupee' is written everywhere in the [site](http://5thpillar.org/programs/zero-rupee-note)." On that web page, all "zero rupee" are either "zero rupee note" or "zero rupee notes". (Hence, my first comment under the OP question.)

Answer (score 2):

Good question!

If you are talking about the word to be printed **on the note**, it should be 'rupees'

> Zero Rupees

Why? Because 'zero' is plural (it has been discussed thousands of times that [why 'zero' is plural](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=is%20zero%20plural&oq=is%20zero%20plural&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i22i30l9.52910.54755.0.54955.14.9.0.3.3.0.188.521.0j3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..8.6.539.GqxsWzGparI); Some say that ['only 1 is singular in English'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38293/why-is-zero-plural), others say it is [grammatically synonymous with 'not any'](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/2k18cq/eli5_why_is_0_plural_like_0_seconds_or_0_apples/); ...and so on; some simply raise a question -[why we say 0.5 apples](http://www.writinggooder.com/2013/11/why-is-zero-plural/)?...anyway, I *won't get into it*).

And I consider that you already know how to refer *that* note [you wrote 'a zero-rupee note'].