# How can I explain to a non-native why the plural of a noun isn't used adjectivally?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, singular-vs-plural

How can I explain to a non-native speaker that while this is correct:

> The felling of trees.

And this is also correct:

> tree felling

This is not:

> *trees felling

To a non-native it seems very reasonable that since many trees are being felled and given that *the felling of trees* uses the plural, the inverse form would also use the plural and become *trees felling*.

To a native speaker such as myself, the latter is very obviously wrong, but I couldn't figure out how to formalize this into a rule that a non-native can understand.

Comment: The question is really why the plural of a noun isn't used adjectivally.  It isn't only with gerund.   Tree frogs not trees frogs.   Tree diseases not trees diseases.

Comment: @TRomano indeed, good point. Same question though. Why? It is blindingly obvious to me and I thought it would be trivial to explain but it isn't.

Comment: We don't use the plural noun as an adjective. Why not? Thinking about that gives me a head ache and a nose bleed, as if I'd been hit with a tire iron or a golf club.  Perhaps what we're really seeing is a compound noun formation (noun noun) which we treat orthographically as separate words but shouldn't?

Comment: I wonder if this happens more often among learners from non-western languages? Is it exclusively? Or it happens to anyone whose first language is not English.

Comment: @TRomano we're discussing this in the [ELU chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage), if you're interested.

Comment: @DamkerngT. this came up when I was proofreading a presentation written by a French friend. I would guess it would occur among learners of any language that has the _felling of trees_ construct but not the _tree felling_ one.

Comment: There's a [related question on ELU about this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/307728/why-in-british-english-is-it-map-room-singular-map-but-games-room-plura). It doesn't answer your question per se but there are plenty of examples and a few insights.

Comment: See also [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/24200/32) here.

Comment: @StoneyB that's very interesting, especially the quote from Leech that explains the existence of some plural forms, thanks. Do you have any insight on why the singular is the default though? We've been hashing this out in the ELU chat room and the consensus seems to be "because".

Comment: @terdon Well, this sort of compounding is 'designed' to simplify the surface structure: to move what would otherwise be expressed by morphological or prepositional case-marking into the hearer's inference; so I don't think we need to look any further than the fact that the sg form is morphologically the simplest and semantically the most generic.

Comment: @StoneyB that makes sense and is indeed probably the best answer I'm likely to get. A gaggle of ELU regulars were unable to come up with anything better, though they did demonstrate that it is even more complex than it appears. Care to whip that into an answer?

Comment: @terdon I wouldn't feel comfortable offering it as an answer (Answer) without a good deal of research stretching back into OE -- and I just don't have time for that right now.

Comment: @StoneyB: Fun fact: Dutch uses the same construction, but we can use either the simple singular as in English, or what is perceives as a plural on -en-, or -e-, or what I think is a genitive -s-. Even with the same word. Rechtbank (court of law), rechtsgebied (field of law), rechteloos (lawless), rechtenstudie ("the study of law"; this one is explained by the fact that the official name of the academic programme is "rechten", but -en- is extremely common with other words). In general, there is no semantic difference and it's hard to predict with connective (if any) is used.

Comment: ... Oh, to complicate things further, -e- and -en- sound exactly the same, because -n is not pronounced in syllables ending on -en.

Comment: Being a non-native-english-speaker, I believe this is a much more difficult feature to explain when it comes to Latin-like languages, such as my own.In those we just don't have nouns used adjectivally, the only possibility is to write something like "the felling of the tree/trees" so we get very confused when we meet with these different structures.

Comment: Do you think you could use *tree felling* in a complete sentence?  It's possible that the grammatical status of *tree felling* could be different in different sentences, which could change the answer.

Comment: @snailboat *Tree felling is not allowed in national parks* for example.

Comment: It's impossible to do any snowboarding where there's been lots of treefelling.

Comment: See http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2014/02/14/pluralisms/ and https://britishisms.wordpress.com/2015/06/10/covers-band/ and especially the link in the latter to [the paper by Elisa Sneed](http://elisasneed.weebly.com/uploads/2/9/9/2/2992676/cls.pdf) (pdf).

Comment: @AlanCarmack thanks! Those were very interesting reads. They all focus on noun-noun compounds though. My feeling, which I can't quite articulate, is that noun+verb and noun+noun are somehow different. There is, somehow, a different syntactical relationship between the two parts of a _tree trimmer_  and _tree trimming_. I certainly feel that _trees trimmer_ is less objectionable than _trees trimming_. But I digress, none of this was in my original question, my understanding of the issue has grown enormously since posting.

Comment: Well, I was thrown by the first comment to this post and your response to it. Plus the line between a noun and a verbal noun (trimming, felling) is slim sometimes (i. e., building, beginning). What are the legitimate examples of plural noun + verbal noun (-ing) that you've run across? @terdon Certainly, it seems to me,  a doubles hitter does doubles hitting.

Comment: @AlanCarmack that's very reasonable. As I said, I wasn't too clear on what I was asking myself. The question has evolved (in my mind, if not necessarily in the post itself) in response to the comments here and the [long discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/conversation/plural-singular-compounds) in the ELU chat room. As for legitimate examples, I don't know that there are any (though there probably are), it;s just that I was hoping for a clear rule that explain _why_ there aren't any.

Comment: Highly interesting question, one I've not thought much on previously. Yeah, seems perhaps that some/many of the noun + noun can be converted to noun + verbal noun: drugs running; arms/weapons dealing; jobs reporting; shoes selling (just kidding on that one).

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/425983/pluralization-rules-with-prepositional-phrases , https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292770/number-of-genitive-object-in-a-nominal-compound , https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48636/plural-nouns-in-nominal-compounds

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no simple explanation, and explanations given by linguists are not to date convincing. See, for example,  [Sneed's work](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85654/how-can-i-explain-to-a-non-native-why-the-plural-of-a-noun-isnt-used-adjectival?noredirect=1#comment165785_85654), which builds on earlier work.

You can say that there is a rising trend, that seems to correlate with the increased use of *nouns + noun* combination (e. g., nowadays one is more likely a *Cubs fan* rather than a *Cub fan*). There is now *covers band* and not just *cover band*; *jobs report*, *drugs dealer* (and  one thinks, *drugs dealing*).

Just spotted: *[birds conservation](https://www.rt.com/news/240841-eagle-dubai-camera-flight-record/)*. This seems to be a British English usage, and such *nouns + noun* are used more often in BrE than AmE.

I found ESPN and the *Washington Post* both using *Numbers Crunching*, which seems novel compared to the singular option. You are free to google your favorite expression and see if anyone is (yet) using it in the plural.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to explain it when there is no simple explanation. It should be sufficient to say that in compound nouns of the type noun + noun 
the first noun or subnoun is normally singular with a few exceptions.

But of course, one may think about why the singular is preferred. It might be a simple case of shortening: horse trainer is shorter and easier to speak than horses trainer.

Another reason might have been that in spoken language it might have been disturbing to decide whether girls class or girls' class was said, and that
girl class was simply unambiguous.

Comment: Because when I posted this question, I hadn't yet spent 3 hours discussing it in the ELU chat room and believed there was a simple explanation.

Comment: You might find this link useful :) http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/compound-nouns