# Why is "letter" not plural in "two letter words"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, attributive-nouns, measure-expressions

Why is "letter" not plural in "two letter words"?

For me it's very strange as the equivalent in French would be plural but my English friend finds it totally normal.

Comment: In French, you would say "mots de deux lettres" right? The equivalent English structure is "words of two letters," where the plural is indeed used. But "two-letter words" (I think it is best to write it with a hyphen) uses a construction which has no exact equivalent in French (just as the French "soupe à l'oignon" construction has no exact equivalent in English).

Comment: How that is written in French is irrelevant. I bet in German one would write that as a single word, but that doesn't mean you have to concatenate words in English.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev In my understanding the point is not about how it's written in French, rather it's the fact that - unlike `words of two letters`, which does have an exact French equivalent and both use the plural - the expression `two-letter words` has no exact equivalent in French, and such English expression needs the singular; same as [two-year old](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/43201/18911).  Regardless, I also have the feeling that the hyphen is kind of key here.

Comment: In french you would use a similar adjective form : `un mot doublement lettré` if you really want something equivalent, which is not plural either. I agree nobody use such constructs in french.

Comment: Relevant: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/85654/2547

Comment: @SantiBailors: yes, the hyphen is key. But that should be _two-year-old_. A two-year-old child is two years old. (Many high-ranking journalists don't get this.)

Comment: I think hyphenating all three words only works if they are being used to modify a noun ("two-year-old child" vs. "a two-year old") or an inanimate object. As a descriptive noun, I always see the second hyphen left off with "old" in place of the missing "child". This appears to be a regular if non-standard transformation when discussing a person. You wouldn't use it for a building.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Measure phrases are special noun phrases that we use to explain how long or big or heavy or expensive something is:

- The programme was **ten minutes**.
- The walk was **five miles**.
- The meal was **twenty pounds**.
- The word is only **three letters**

These measure phrases all include a number, like *one* or *seven* and a noun afterwards. In the examples above these measure phrases are Complements of the verb. You will notice that the nouns are all in the plural, as we expect.

We can also use measure phrases like these to modify nouns:

- a **ten minute** programme.
- a **five mile** walk.
- a **twenty pound** note.
- a **three letter** word.

Here, these measure phrases are modifying the nouns *programme*, *walk* and *note*. They are in the same position that we find adjectives in. When we use measure phrases in this way, the noun in the measure phrase is not plural. We see no S on the ends of the words in the measure phrases.

Really this is not very surprising. Why? Well, when we use a noun to modify another noun, we don't usually use plurals (there are exceptions of course). So we usually say:

- a **book** collector
- an **ant**eater
- a **cherry** tart

We don't say:

- *a books collector
- *an ants eater
- *a cherries tart

Comment: You don't think that "three-letter" should be a compound rather than a syntactic construction?

Comment: @BillJ I've never really considered 'compound adjectives' based on measure phrases as compound adjectives. I was very surprised today to find that H&P do. I've always regarded them as nominals in attributive function. I don't think there's much (if any) difference between a three mile walk and a twenty dollar bill and a three letter word ... Maybe there is - but I can't see it. Is there any difference in their syntactic properties?

Comment: @BillJ H&P call them compound adjective constructions ... If you felt like editing my post to make it CGEL compliant, please do!!!! I'm not up with H&P on compounds. And I'll defer to your better judgement here ... Also, I don't understand why the only criteria mentioned by H&P for these being c-adj as opposed to nominals is that they don't inflect. After all other nominals don't inflect either! "Book" in "book collector", for example! (Scratches head. Shrugs ...)

Comment: I think "three-letter" is a noun-centred compound noun (det+noun) as attributive modifier of "word" in your example. I know dictionaries are unreliable, but they all give "four-letter" as a single noun in "four-letter word". The fact that it is hyphenated is an indication that "four-letter" is  single lexeme, not a syntactic construction of modifier + noun (see CGEL p1644)

Comment: @BillJ We can coordinate the numerals there: "Two, three and four letter words". However, I can see two-letter as a compound noun - but not as a compound adjective, which is what I think H&P would say it was. I'm with you on that.

Comment: @Araucaria: parts of words can be (or at least can appear to be) coordinated (e.g. "super- and subordinate structures"), which I believe some see as evidence against the idea of a strict division between a lexical level and higher level. I share your confusion about why "two letter," whether thought of as a phrase or as a compound, would be lexically classified by H&P as an adjective rather than as a noun.

Comment: @sumelic If the main component of a compound word is a noun, then the word can only be a noun. There is nothing adjectival about "three-letter" in "three-letter word". "Three-letter" is a noun-centred compound noun modifying "word". H&P would say the same thing.

Comment: @BillJ That's why I'd have thought, but not so it seems - unfortunately. See CamGEL p.470 and also more specifically p.1660 4.3.3 "Other forms" : **One productive type that merits mention involves measure expressions with a singular noun base: *a three-inch nail, a five-mile walk, a two-year moratorium*. These do not qualify as nominals, which have plural forms of the noun: *The nail is three inches long; We walked five miles;* and so on. These compound adjectives can [...]**" Btw, notice that *five miles* isn't actually a nominal there - it is an NP!!

Comment: Ah, got it! They are compound adjectives because the main noun component can't be pluralised. Unlike, for example the compound nouns "city-dweller(s)" or "shirt-sleeve(s)", you can't say "a three-inches nail", or "a three-letters word". Well spotted A. (I still take "three-letter" as a hyphenated compound, though, not a syntactic construction)

Comment: @BillJ That argument of theirs won't go through though! (It seems to me) In general nominal modifiers of nouns don't take plural inflections (and most of the exceptional cases are actually probably disguised genitive forms as opposed to normal plurals). We don't see "books collectors" or "cherries tarts"!!! That argument's a no-go. Why should we make an exception here? (Also the stress facts don't tally.* 'Three letter 'word* is what we'd expect from three stressed word in a row - the middle one would become less prominent). The only good point is about not being able ...

Comment: But aren't we talking specifically about compounds here, where different considerations apply

Comment: @BillJ But why are the considerations different? If modifying nominals don't have plural inflections (in general), why should we expect compound nominals to have plural inflections? Isn't that the point of a compound - that the two words behave like a single word would? (scratches head - still confused ....)

Comment: Seems reasonable, but I have to point out that those example phrases at the top all sound odd. Probably BrE vs AmE. The program was ten minutes *long*, the walk was five miles *long*, the meal *cost* twenty pounds, the word is only three letters *long*.

Comment: Hi folks, just FYI this answer has been automatically flagged for having a bunch of comments. Can we make sure that the salient points here have been incorporated into the answer and possibly move this into a chat room? I'm reluctant to trim the conversation just yet because I think it's valuable, but I would like to whittle it down eventually.

Comment: I've submitted an edit hyphenating the second group, because I was taught that when a multi-word phrase is used as an adjective to modify a noun following it, the phrase is hyphenated, like "ten-minute programme"

Comment: @MontyHarder Thanks for the edit suggestion. I'm not against hyphenating such combinations. But I don't like teaching them (and don't like, therefore, using them here). The reason is just that the hyphenation of such modifiers is not consistent by convention, is not used by many writers, and generally makes things difficult for learners. Given a (debatably mandatory) hyphen or an S, the S issue is fundamentally important, and the hyphen one waivable. (My aesthetic preferenc is for the hyphen - but that aesthetics for you! :-))

Comment: I (non-native speaker, admittedly) have an odd feeling with "Two, three and four letter words"; immediate parsing makes me think it's two, three or four words, with letters. Only when this doesn't make much sense I realize that the numbers belong to "letter". Part of that is exactly the question's issue: letter is singular, words is plural, so the numbers indicating a plurality must surely refer to the plural noun. I'd hyphenate for clarity: "Two-, three- and four-letter words". But then as a German my bias is a bit off concerning word chains.

Comment: _"Really this is not very surprising."_ well... for an English speaker. :)
In French we wouldn't say "a book collector" but "a collector of books" ("un collectionneur de livres"), so it doesn't make "two letter words" any less strange to us.
Thanks for your thorough explanation though!

Comment: @Romanito Actually, that's a perfectly grammaticl and idiomatic way of saying it in English too - though much less common. I have often described myself as "a collector of books" - and we use the plural *books* there too. There, the word *books* is in a preposition phrase, instead of occurring before the noun. It's works differently there. It's complicated! :-)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider A lot of native speakers do indeed use hyphenation there - but not consistently. Others don't though. [Here's a page from the Scrabble website](http://nsw.scrabble.org.au/backup/2&3&4%20complimentary.pdf), for example. Aesthetically, I agree with you ...

Comment: I wanted to learn the answer to the question that came up in the comments, so I made a new post on ELU: [Syntax of “two-letter word,” “five-mile run,” “three-hour play”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/383539)

Answer (score 21):

You might mean 'two-letter words'.
Be aware that there's a real hyphen between 'two' and 'letter', with which we don't use plural from of the latter word because such a hyphened phrase is used as an adjective, not a noun. For example:

- I went on a trip of four **days** after my three-**day** work was done.
- A boy of five **years** and another six-**year**-old girl.

Comment: From my observation US writers usually omit the hyphen

Comment: @im_chc : I see that as well, but I'm afraid it's from ignorance, not because of a grammatical standard. I dislike that practice very much. I also very rarely see the correct use of the hyphen in numbers, such as "one thousand four hundred thirty-eight"

Comment: _"A boy of five years old and....?"_  Really?  I would expect _"A boy of five years and...."_

Comment: @iBug I went ahead and incorporated Adam's suggestion into your answer.  The example was ungrammatical with *old*.  However, it is your answer, so please feel free to edit it as you see fit (including rolling back the change if you disagree).

Comment: @snailplane A bit of joke. I'm feeling that the people who know the grammar of a language very well is rarely a native speaker as that language. As a Chinese I'm often confused about how deep western learners study Chinese and I also see a lot of western people complaining about Asian English learners studying too deep to some extent.

Comment: Going off topic now (or should that read "off-topic") but I was taught at school that "five years old" is the correct phrase, while "five years" is wrong. Was my teacher mistaken, or has the language changed since the 20th century?

Comment: @MrLister The boy *is* five years old, but he is *of* five years.

Comment: @DCShannon Ah, context.

Comment: Really, the hyphen doesn't matter to this question because it is spoken the same way with or without the hyphen. I.e. the presence or absence of a hyphen (written) doesn't change the underlying grammar (spoken).

Answer (score 6):

The measure phrases, such as "two-letter", act as adjectives. We do not pluralize adjectives in English.

Any accurate translation is an equivalent: any phrase that gets across the same meaning, or as close to that meaning as possible. We should never primarily try for a word-for-word translation as our primary goal.

I don't have the "reputation" to comment on others' posts, but let's improve on sentences such as "The meal was 20 pounds." No, the meal cost 20 pounds. (More precise, easily translated, and enjoyable to read.)

Comment: Also removes ambiguity. "The meal was 20 pounds" could be talking about how much it weighed (that's a heavy meal!)

Comment: @Adeptus ... or about eating 20 £; good point.

Comment: @Adeptus Someone eat a meal weighing 20 lb? I think abbreviations are better here as "lb" and "£" provide no ambiguity but "pound" does.

Answer (score 3):

For a combination of 2 reasons:

1. English has a Germanic grammar, and in Germanic languages, "twoletterword" is one word – a noun! It does not matter that English writes it in 3 words (and as a result, calls it a *noun phrase*, not a noun) – Germanic languages are older than writing. As far as I know, all other Germanic languages would write it as "twoletterword", which may better represent how they work.
2. Inflecting a word's constituents is undefined in English. You can only inflect the word as a whole, which is indistinguishable from inflecting the last constituent word (because Germanic compound words read like domain names – most significant part last, which is also where the inflection is).

Answer (score 1):

A compound noun combines multiple nouns to make a new noun, and treats the first noun as an adjective to describe the second noun. Two letters and word are combining to make a new noun. A car salesman is another example. The true noun here is salesman. The word car is there to tell us what kind of salesman they are, so it's being used like an adjective and therefore should not be pluralized like you might a noun. Many compound nouns have no spaces between their constituent nouns, such as keyboard, dishwasher and bathroom. Those examples demonstrate the sheer power of compound nouns--the ability to just take a singular noun and tack it on to another to make a new word. Awesome. And imagine how funny it would sound if you had to add s/es to the first of the two nouns (keysboard, disheswasher, bathsroom...).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is an understanding of the implicit but unspoken content:
a 'letter' means an "instance of the letter object'
a 'word' means a collection of letter objects

Thus a "two letter word" means two instances of the letter object combined in a word
while a word of 20 letters is a collection of size 20 containing letter objects

The English language recognises that the two usages describe different things and therefore have different structures