# How I say I work on a project that existed for 10 years?

Tags: sentence-structure, measure-expressions

I was thinking about

> I worked on a 10 year duration project

Is there any mistake or awkward construction on this phrase? I don't how to search about this type of phrase, where you state a number, a measurement unit and the aspect being measured. What is the correct solution?

Comment: @COX1 [This](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/123894/why-is-letter-not-plural-in-two-letter-words) answers your question.

Comment: I didn't find what this uniqe structure is called in grammar.

Comment: @COX1 If you have a different question, you should [ask it using the "Ask Question" button](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) so you can get a proper answer. You can link to this question, and the question Lars provided you as context to explain how your question arose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing more context, I would write "a 10-year-long project". For example, [Great Migration Inspires 10-Year-Long Project by Hyde Park Photographer](https://www.dnainfo.com/chicago/20150806/hyde-park/great-migration-inspires-10-year-long-project-by-hyde-park-photographer).

I would use the hyphens, but I think it is also acceptable to leave them off. For example, [A Year Long Photography Project](https://clockworkclouds.wordpress.com/2017/10/18/debs-52week-photography-project/)

Some learners might want to say "10 year**s** long project", because it seems logical that when you have 10 of something you would use the plural, but that would not be correct (See [Why is "letter" not plural in "two letter words"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/123894/)). There is this question on EL&U that discusses "years-long": [Is “yearslong” a word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141101/is-yearslong-a-word) You can say "years-long project" to describe something that lasted multiple years without saying exactly how many years.