# Singular or plural form before the word set / list

Tags: grammar

I have been always confused which is proper to use: singular or plural form before the word set, list, or container of multiple things?

For example:

- values set or it should be value set
- key list or keys list
- integer set or integers set

Comment: In all your examples the first term is a ***noun adjunct*** (noun used as adjective), which is almost always ***singular*** (thus your car might have a ***car radio***, but not a ***cars radio*** or possessive ***car's radio*** or ***cars' radio***). The fact that both your *second* words have similar meanings is irrelevant. We don't have special rules of grammar for such details.

Comment: [This](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/24244/32) may be of help.

Answer (score 9):

Singular before, plural after:

- Value set or set of values
- Key list or list of keys
- Integer set or set of integers
- Donut box or box of donuts

The reason it is singular is because it is acting as an adjective, like FumbleFingers said. So in the case of "integer set," integer is seen as an adjective modifying set, telling what kind of set it is.