# Can I write "sustaining of relations" as "relations sustaining"?

Tags: word-order, gerunds, prepositional-phrases, present-participles, attributive-nouns

Using "of" more than once seems weird to me, so I'm trying to avoid such repetition.

For example there is

> a notion of sustaining of relations

which I want to replace with

> a notion of relations sustaining

Is this replacement grammatically correct?

Feel free to post a short answer and/or a link if it's a general rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it right,

> a notion of sustaining relations

would be adequate for what you are trying to say

> a notion of relations sustaining

doesn't make much sense without further context.

Answer (score 3):

> ... a notion of relations sustaining ...

is not idiomatic. The usual construction with an attributive noun casts the noun in the singular, "relation sustaining", although there are [exceptions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/24244/32).

But the *of* is unnecessary; in fact, *VERBing of OBJECT* usually sounds rather old-fashioned in contemporary discourse, suggesting bureaucratic volubility or 19th-century canons of elegance. *Sustaining* as a gerund retains many of its properties as a verb, including the capacity to take an object: it's perfectly OK to speak of

> ... a notion of sustaining relations ...