# Is a possessive apostrophe required after minutes in "After a few minutes' use..."?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Wondering if a possessive apostrophe is correct after 'minutes' in the sentence: "After a few minutes' use, the hairdryer stopped working."?  I know it's correct to have one in the sentence "In a few weeks' time, I'll be on holiday." but not sure if it's the same?

Comment: Yes, you have to have an **-s'** for it to be correct: "a few **minutes'** use."

Comment: According to snailplane in [this rather related--but not duplicate--post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14290/shouldnt-five-minute-walk-be-five-minutes-walk-in-this-sentence), the apostrophe is optional rather than required. I'm a bit on the fence, myself, and would probably chicken out and use farnsy's option.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use an apostrophe in both your hairdryer and holiday examples.

You could also write

> After a few minutes of use, the hairdryer stopped working

which is the somewhat more common way to say this.