# Why do the nouns in these phrases have -s?

Tags: grammar

I have some questions related to these phrases

> admission**s** policy;
>   material**s** design/writing

Why do "admissions" and "materials" have -s? Shouldn't they be in the singular form because they stand before another noun/gerund?

In this article, we have "letter writing", not "letter**s** writing"

> https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2016/nov/26/from-me-with-love-lost-art-letter-writing

How can this be explained? What is the rule here?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14290/shouldnt-five-minute-walk-be-five-minutes-walk-in-this-sentence/14312#14312

Answer (score 1):

There is a "rule" which permits both singular and plural attributives (pre-head internal dependents). On pages 439 and 444 in *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Huddleston and Pullum (2002), it says, respectively: *Pre-head complements are usually realized by nominals* and *Internal modifiers in pre-head position are realised by [...] nominals in plain and genitive case*. Neither of the "rules" places any restrictions on inflection regarding their number. [Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/310499/71740)'s a little bit on the difference between modifiers and complements.

Regarding everything else – it's up to what sounds better to English-speaking people. A rule of thumb could probably be: if it normally comes not as a single item, but as a multitude of items/phenomena/whatever, then that's how it could be denoted in writing (i.e., in the plural).

<sub>(transcribed from comments)</sub>