# Is it '55-minutes meeting' or '55-minute meeting'?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number, compounds

Which of the following two constructions is correct?

1. a 55-minute meeting
2. a 55-minutes meeting

That is, should 'minute' be followed by 's'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shouldn't "five minute walk" be "five minutes walk" in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14290/shouldnt-five-minute-walk-be-five-minutes-walk-in-this-sentence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an adjective, it would be "a 55-minute meeting" without the "s".  As a noun, "the meeting will last 55 minutes."

To put it simply, adjectives do not get pluralized, while nouns do.

Comment: Yes, although it's probably best to call measure expressions like "55-minute" a **compound** adjective, the base is actually the singular noun, "minute", and it's this **noun** that is not by convention pluralised.