# What does "One and a half" take after it? A singular noun or plural?

Tags: plural-forms, singular

I read it somewhere but forgot it. What does "One and a half" take after it? A singular noun or plural? Why?

> One and a half hour or hours? 
>   One and a half dollar or dollars? 
>   One and a half day or days. And so on...

Here in India, I always hear *one and a half hour* arguing *hour* is applicable to the *half* as in *half an hour* and **not** *half an hours*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually hear plural come next: *One and a half teaspoons of sugar, one-and-a-half pages of data*, e.g.

Also, you can switch to a singular noun if you reword the phrase:

- The play went on for another one-and-a-half hours
- The play when on for another hour and a half

I found this usage note in Macmillan:

> **When half forms part of a number, the most common structure is one and a half, two and a half, three and a half, etc.**
>   ✗ Tourists can visit any of these sites within one and half hours.
>   ✓ Tourists can visit any of these sites within one and a half **hours**.
>   ✗ They made us wait for two hours and a half for our visa.
>   ✓ They made us wait two and a half hours for our visa.
>
> **Always use a plural noun in this structure**:
>   ✗ A 90-minute movie might last two and a half hour with commercials.
>   ✓ A 90-minute movie might last two and a half hours with commercials.

The last example shows *two and a half*, but the wording would be the same for *one and a half*:

✓ A 60-minute movie might last one and a half hours with commercials.

Incidentally, you can find many forums about this very issue simply by Googling ["one and a half hours"](https://www.google.com/#q=%22one+and+a+half+hours%22). Evidently, you're not the first person to wonder about this.

Moreover, some sources recommend using [hyphens](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/numbers_as_compound_adjectives.htm#Yv2Wv6kfhvp7tHAi.99):

> When used as compound adjectives, expressions like four-and-a-quarter and two-and-a-half should be hyphenated to aid your reader and to eliminate ambiguity.
>
> - Expressions like *three-and-a-half* (as in *three-and-a-half ounces*) are classified as compound adjectives and should be hyphenated. This is done to group the words together to show they are all part of the same adjective.

But this is a [style issue](http://ask.metafilter.com/153895/Hyphens-in-fractions), not a prescriptive one.

Here's where it might get tricky: when preceded by an article, and used as a compound adjective, you use a singular unit, not a plural one. Notice how the wording changes in this dialog:

> We played a two-and-a-half hour game.
>   *Really, was it that long?*
>   Yes, it lasted two and a half hours.

Comment: +1 especially for the last portion. That is nice. Thank you. But won't it take all hyphened: We played a *two-and-a-half-hour game*? Because if you leave *hour* like that, it might again take plural *hours?*

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked on ELU long before ELL existed. The overwhelmingly top-rated answer there says:-

> [*the rule is ... use the singular only when talking of **exactly one***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2148/2637)

Probably the only context where this doesn't apply is if the amount *and the unit of measurement* both form part of a [hyphenated adjectival phrase](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/040201hyphadj.htm) as covered by [this earlier ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6434/a-ten-years-old-boy-or-a-ten-year-old-boy). For example,...

> *I recently watched him play a [**one-and-a-half-hour**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20space%20thus%20cleared%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22one-and-a-half%20hour%20game%22&tbm=bks) game of blindfold chess.*