# Which is correct to use- is or are

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Which is correct  to use- **is** or **are**-

> - Five kilometers ***is/are*** hard to travel.
> - sixty miles ***is/are*** good distance.
> - 20 minutes ***is/are*** remaining .

Comment: Which do you think is correct?

Comment: Are these test questions?

Comment: @Valkor Yes. I am confused, which to choose is or are

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mile or miles? Singular or plural?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106351/mile-or-miles-singular-or-plural)